# LINQ Join returning IQueryable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I've a relationship between 3 tables like this

[image]

I wanna have a method that given a parameter of type *table1* and the *DbContext* I get all the related rows from *table3* passing through *table2*

Here's my implementation

```
public static IQueryable<table3> GetRows(
  EntitiesContext context, 
  table1 row)
{
  var table3Rows =
    from t2 in row.table2
    join t3 in context.table3 on t2.IdTable3 equals t3.Id
    select t3;

  return table3Rows;
}
```

The problem with this approach is that I can't return *table3Rows* because it's *IEnumerable* not *IQueryable*.

Is there any workaround to return *IQueryable* when using *join*?

I need *IQueryable* because I plan to do some other queries against the result.

Comment: Check this post - https://blog.hompus.nl/2010/08/26/joining-an-iqueryable-with-an-ienumerable/#gs.CQPGsx4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not going to be able to use the navigation property if you have an already materialized `Table1` object.  If you have an `IQueryable<Table1>` then you can use the general approach you're using and the result will just naturally be an `IQueryable<Table3>`.

Since you have a materialized table row you'll need to query the DB for the `Table2` items rather than using the navigation property.

```
public static IQueryable<table3> GetRows(
  EntitiesContext context, 
  table1 row)
{
  var table3Rows =
    from t2 in context.table2
    where row.Table2Id == t2.Id
    from t3 in t2.Table3 //here we can use a navigation property, since it's not on a materialized object.
    select t3;

  return table3Rows;
}
```

Comment: This does not compile.

Comment: @TamasIonut Why not?  Obviously I've made a few assumptions about the OP's schema, which may need to be adjusted based on his specific names, but the premise is what's important here, and that's not flawed.

Comment: the "on" keyword after the first "from"

Comment: @TamasIonut Right, fixed.

Comment: Yes, but this implies some changes: Table1 ("row" instance) does not has a reference to table2 (the "Table2Id") + the second from still doesn't compile.

Comment: I'm pretty skeptic that is possible to do joins and still have an IQueryable as a result (without going to IEnumerable - in memory).

Comment: @TamasIonut Again, like I said, this is making an assupmtion about the OP's naming conventions, but we *do* know that there is a foreign key on `Table1` pointing to `Table2`.  If it's named differently than what I have, the OP will need to correct the name, but we *do* know that there is one as it is described in the question.

Comment: @TamasIonut Why wouldn't you have an `IQueryable` after filtering an `IQueryable` or calling `Join` on an `IQueryable` (to another `IQueryable`)?  Of course, you're answer *must* be doing the work in memory, because you're calling `Select` on an `IEnumerable`, thus there is no possibility of it being a DB query.

Comment: @TamasIonut It's *absolutely* appropriate to have a second `from` in a LINQ query.  It will perform a `SelectMany`.  You can look at an intro LINQ tutorial if you'd like to learn more about it.

Comment: @Servy you're absolutely right! I didn't realize that I was using a materialized object in the query. In fact, the method's signature is constrained to use a materialized object. That's why I was getting an IEnumerable instead of an IQueryable. Thank you, you saved my day. And thank you guys for trying to help me.